# How to chose concurrency level of a concurrent dictionary

Tags: .net, concurrentdictionary

I'm using a concurrent dictionary to store about two million records and want to know what to initialize the concurrency level of my dictionary to.

The MSDN page has the following comment in its example code:

> The higher the `concurrencyLevel`, the higher the theoretical number of operations that could be performed concurrently on the `ConcurrentDictionary`. However, global operations like resizing the dictionary take longer as the `concurrencyLevel` rises.

This is the best I could find that explains what the concurrencyLevel means and yet it is still very vague.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The most important thing to understand is that even if you have more concurrent accesses than the `concurrencyLevel`, operations will still be thread-safe. That is, setting `concurrencyLevel` is a matter of performance, not correctness.

`concurrencyLevel` specifies the number of independent locks which are available for map operations. Each lock is associated with a different subset of the hash space, so accessing a given element requires holding a particular lock. This means that one thread's access *may* block another thread's, even if the number of concurrent accesses is well below `concurrencyLevel`. Raising the number of locks reduces the probability of lock contentions, but increases the cost of operations which must acquire all locks (those which examine the collection as a whole, such as `Count`, `IsEmpty`, or `Values`, as well as `Add()` when it needs to resize the table).

Profiling your application is really the only way to determine the optimal `concurrencyLevel`. Setting it to the expected number of worker threads is a good start, though.

Comment: Agree on the profiling part. It really is the only way to tell.

Comment: Can you explain what tools you might use to profile this (i.e. VS Concurrency Visualizer).  Also, specifically what am I looking for in the during profiling that indicates to me I should increase / change the concurrencyLevel?

Comment: Old post but JetBrains DotTrace is a good product to start with for profiling.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set the initial capacity and don't know what `concurrencyLevel` you should use, just resort to `Environment.ProcessorCount`, since the collections default concurrency level value is `PlatformHelper.ProcessorCount`.